# expand a dataframe as given by variables in another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Can someone help with this:

in a new df2 var2 should be added and df2$var1 should be expanded by 
df1$var2, filling new lines in Var1 & Var3 as given by variables in df1:

```
(df1 <- expand.grid(Var2 = letters[1:4], Var1 = 1:3)[1:10, 2:1])
(df2 <- data.frame(Var1 = 1:4, Var3 = LETTERS[1:4]))
```

wanted:

```
   Var1 Var2 Var3
1     1    a    A
2     1    b    A
3     1    c    A
4     1    d    A
5     2    a    B
6     2    b    B
7     2    c    B
8     2    d    B
9     3    a    C
10    3    b    C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the merge function:

```
(df3 <- merge(df1, df2))
```